# Error in install rpy2 on windows 10

Tags: pip, rpy2

I got this error when using `pip to install rpy2` on my computer:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install rpy2
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached rpy2-2.8.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Warning: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command (R) in the PATH.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\isaac\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-_n5cg0\rpy2\
```

I think this is just an error with the `R` directory on my computer.  How do I indicate the correct directory on `pip`?

Comment: Make sure `R` is installed.  You will likely have to add the filepath for your R.exe file in your system PATH.  See the GUI option here on how to add paths http://johnatten.com/2014/12/07/adding-and-editing-path-environment-variables-in-windows/

Comment: ya my R are instaled, i put this directory and still dont work 
http://prnt.sc/cbgor9 
uguuu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem resolve, i just download rpy2.whl and add this paths here
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3npm2b/tutorial_how_to_install_rpy2_on_windows_to_bridge/

Answer (score 1):

1. Download [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) and [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)
2. Run `conda install -c r rpy2` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Adding environment variable `R_HOME` to your environment should help:

[image]